# Which in-game events are unlockable by bringing a specific Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-series

As you probably know, some in-game events are unlocked if you go to a specific place while having a specific Pokémon on you or in the first party slot. What I want is a complete list of those events.

I'm mainly interested in events unlocking other Pokémon (such as the Sinjoh ruins event) and less in events unlocking items (such as the Gracidea event) or Formes (such as the Deoxys meteorites).

I know of the following:

1. Arceus unlocks the Sinjoh ruins event in HG/SS. (any one, Movie and Azure Flute can unlock it once each) -> lets you pick Dialga, Palkia or Giratina.
2. Celebi (Movie) unlocks Zorua event in B/W.
3. Raikou, Entei or Suicune (Movie, shiny) unlocks Zoroark event in B/W.
4. Regigigas (not sure where it's from, but it's Lv.100) unlocks Regi shrines in Platinum.
5. Regice, Regirock and Registeel unlock that shrine where you can get Regigigas in D/P/Pt.
6. Kyogre and Groudon (caught in HG or SS, respectively) unlock Rayquaza at the same location where the respective former Pokémon was found in HG/SS.

So, are there any more of these in Gen III+?

Comment: I believe this question is too broad when you have it covering multiple generations, especially when you consider that each generation tends to have multiple sets of games in it. I'd suggest asking a separate question for each generation to narrow your scope.

Comment: While each generations has multiple games, those events are usually comsistent across games and quite rare. From my previous searching on google and many fan sites, the ones listed above are the only ones I could find and I don't think there are many more. Also, I believe this is pretty specific in its scope. I might just be missing 2 or 3 of those, and I'm hoping to get a complete list of all those special events. The reason, by the way, is to know which Pokémon I can transfer to newer generations without losing out on the chance to get one of these in-game events.

Comment: If this was a specific question about ONE specific gen, I think it should be fine. but ...

Comment: I don't see how this is too broad. We're talking about something so very specific that it exists roughly twice in each generation. A seperate question for each generation makes no sense in this case. See the accepted answer, which covers exactly what I was asking and is, so I think, complete. If the question was too broad, that answer would be much, much bigger (or incomplete). Also, the question for Gen III would probably have no answer since apparently this kind of in-game events wasn't present there. Not every question spanning multiple generations is too broad by default...

Comment: After having a conversation with LessPop in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13623178#13623178), in addition to the answer showing the scope, I've decided to reconsider my close vote and have thus voted to re-open. I was under the impression that there were 5-6 of these events per game, but it appears I was just remembering incorrectly.

Comment: @scenia Oh, you also wanted to know about such events in Gen III games? I wasn't so sure about it because of the initial tags not having 'pokemon-third-gen', but there is only one I can think of; and it's to unlock... the Regis! I'll add it to my answer if you confirm it.

Comment: @Jerry The Regis in Gen III are those Braille riddles, right? I think they're more or less covered by the actual in game riddles and since they don't require specific unique Pokémon but rather just "usual" catchable and breedable ones, they're not necessarily what I'm looking for. You can still add them if you like, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You already mentioned a few, and I'll be including these in my answer just for completeness and I'm pretty sure it's complete.

---

### Diamond/Pearl

- **Regigigas**

  Unlocked on Snowpoint Temple (Lv 70).

  Requirement: have Regirock, Regice and Registeel in your party.

---

### Platinum

- **Regirock, Regice, Registeel**

  Unlocked on Rock Peak Ruins (Route 228), Iceberg Ruins (Mt. Coronet, Route 216 near the exit) and Iron Ruins (Iron Island) respectively after obtaining the movie Regigigas.

  Requirement: have the movie Regigigas in your party.
- **Regigigas**

  Unlocked on Snowpoint Temple (Lv 1).

  Requirement: have Regirock, Regice and Registeel in your party.

---

### HeartGold/SoulSilver

- **Spiky-eared Pichu**

  Unlocked in Ilex Forest's shrine.

  Requirement: have the Pikachu-coloured Pichu first in your party.
- **Rayquaza** (if that counts)

  Unlocked in Embedded Tower.

  Requirement: get the Jade Orb from Oak by showing him a Kyogre and a Groudon from HeartGold and SoulSilver respectively.
- **Dialga, Palkia or Giratina**

  Unlocked in Sinjoh Ruins.

  Requirement: have an event Arceus walking alongside you.

---

### Black/White

- **Zorua**

  Unlocked in Game Freak building in Castelia City.

  Requirement: obtained an event obtained Celebi from a Gen IV game through PokeTransfer or Relocator.
- **Zoroark**

  Unlocked in Lostlorn Forest.

  Requirement: have an event shiny beast (Entei, Raikou or Suicune) from a Gen IV game through PokeTransfer or Relocator in the party.
- **Terrakion and Virizion** (similar to Rayquaza)

  Unlocked in Trial Chamber (Victory Road) and Rumination Field (Pinwheel Forest).

  Requirement: have captured Cobalion.
- **Landorus**

  Unlocked in Abundant Shrine.

  Requirement: have both Thundurus and Tornadus in party.

---

### Black 2/White 2

- **Regice and Registeel**

  Unlocked in Underground Ruins.

  Requirement for Regice: Have captured Regirock and have the Iceberg Key
  Requirement for Registeel: Have captured Regirock and have the Iron Key.
- **Regigigas**

  Unlocked in Twist Mountain.

  Requirement: have Regirock, Regice and Registeel in party.

---

And there are none that I know of from Pokemon X and Y which has a condition of 'get such or such Pokemon to unlock such Pokemon' (of course, Pokemon obtained through the choice of a player, for instance those which depend on the starter picked, is not considered here as such events).

---

### OmegaRuby/AlphaSapphire

- **Regigigas**

  Unlocked in Island Cave.

  Requirement: Have Regice (nicknamed it and make it hold a "cold item" such as a Casteliacone, Nevermelt Ice, Icy Rock or Snowball), Regirock and Registeel in the party. Regigigas cannot be encountered during nighttime or until after encountering Groudon/Kyogre.
- **Raikou, Entei and Suicune**

  Unlocked while soaring through the mirage spot Trackless Forest.

  Requirement: Have Lugia or Ho-Oh in the party. Raikou appears between HH:00 to HH:19, Entei appears between HH:20 to HH:39 and Suicune appears between HH:40 to HH:59 (HH is the hour of the day).
- **Dialga or Palkia**

  Unlocked while soaring.

  Requirement: Have Uxie, Mesprit and Azelf in party. Dialga appears in Alpha Sapphire and Palkia appears in Omega Ruby.
- **Giratina**

  Unlocked while soaring.

  Requirement: Have Palkia and Dialga in party.
- **Tornadus or Thunderus**

  Unlocked while soaring.

  Requirement: Have Castform in party. Thundurus appears in Alpha Sapphire and Tornadus appears in Omega Ruby.
- **Landorus**

  Unlocked while soaring.

  Requirement: Have Tornadus and Thunderus in party.

Comment: Awesome, this is just what I was looking for. Regirock can be captured in B2/W2 without any requirements, I suppose?

Comment: @scenia Yup. That's why it's not up there.

Comment: Isn't the Regigigas in Snowpoint Temple also available in Platinum? The way you wrote it, it looks like it's not...

Comment: @scenia Oh, yes, that's right. I guess I got sidetracked after applying some headers and separators.

Answer (score 0):

In  addition to Jerry's list in B/W Keldeo will learn the move secret sword if taken to the Moor of Icirrus along with: Cobalion, Virizion and Terrakion

Comment: That doesn't really count as "unlocking other Pokémon", now does it?

Comment: the question is about in-game events not just pokemon

Comment: "Mainly interested in Pokémon, less in the others" means you can include the others if you're writing an answer containing the Pokémon already, but it doesn't warrant its own answer.